How do I add an in-app purchase to my iOS app for tips?
I have seen a few apps where there is an in-app purchase for a tip - a sort of voluntary payment.
I can’t find any information on this sort of thing. Is this just a regular in-app purchase which simply doesn’t unlock anything new?

Maybe this can help you.

Yes.  It is just a non-consumable in app purchase
